# Transition 2D player Position A to B on JAVA

Tags: java, 2d, tile

Am having issues trying to figure out how to translate or 'animate' my player's position to a new tile, this is what am doing :

```
            if (input.right){
                x += 1;
```

Right now am listening for key.inputs and then x++/x--  or y++/y-- on my players position that makes him move pixel by pixel, but i want my player to move exactly to the next tile(32 pixels) with one hit of the key with like a linear transition from the player's tile position to the next tile over time?

Something like (pseudo code i think..)

```
            if input && walking false
               walking = true
               increment 1 by 1  32 ints to X over time?
               after completed walking = false
```

I still cant even figure out the logic behind something like that.

An example is the movement in a game called **Tibia.**

Now Some bits of my code (player related)..

```
GAMECLASS >

public Game()

    player = new Player(playerSpawn.x(), playerSpawn.y(), key);
    player.init(level);

public void run()
    ....
    render();
    frames++;
    ....

public void update()
    key.update();
    player.update();
    level.update();

public void render()
    .....
    int xScroll = ( player.x + 32) - screen.width / 2;
    int yScroll = ( player.y + 32) - screen.height / 2;
    level.render(xScroll, yScroll, screen);
    player.render(screen);

    for (int i =0; i < pixels.length; i++){
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

SCREENCLASS >
    ......
    public int[] pixels;
    public int[] tiles = new int[VIEW_SIZE * VIEW_SIZE];
    .....
    public void renderTile(int xp, int yp, Tile tile){
      xp -= xOffset;
      yp -= yOffset;
     for (int y = 0; y < tile.sprite.SIZE; y++){
        int ya = y + yp;
        for (int x = 0; x < tile.sprite.SIZE; x++){
            int xa = x + xp;
            if (xa < -tile.sprite.SIZE || xa >= width || ya < 0 || ya >= height) break;
            if (xa < 0) xa = 0;
                pixels[xa + ya * width] = tile.sprite.pixels[x + y * tile.sprite.SIZE];
             }
         }

      }

    //THIS IS THE METHOD CALLED TO RENDER THE PLAYER > SEE BELLOW AT THE PLAYER CLASS FOR THE CALL

    public void renderMob(int xp, int yp, Mob mob){
       xp -= xOffset;
       yp -= yOffset;
      for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++){
        int ya = y + yp;
        int ys = y;
        for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++){
            int xa = x + xp;
            int xs = x;
            if (xa < -64 || xa >= width || ya < 0 || ya >= height) break;
            if (xa < 0) xa = 0;
            int col = mob.getSprite().pixels[xs + ys * 64];
            if (mob instanceof Chazer && col == 0xFF9b0000) col = 0xff54ff00;
            if (col != 0xFFFF00FF) pixels[xa + ya * width] = col;
          }
        }   

      }

    PLAYERCLASS >

        public Player(int x , int y, Keyboard input){
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.input = input;
          }

        //PLAYER UPDATE
        public void update(){

        if (anim < 7500) anim++;
        else anim = 0;

        if (input.down)  ya = 1;
        if (input.up)    ya = -1;
        if (input.left)  xa = -1;
        if (input.right) xa = 1;

        //CHECK BELLOW TO THIS MOVE METHOD

        if (xa != 0){
            move(xa, 0);    
        } else if(ya != 0){
             move(0, ya);
          } 
        }


         clear();

       }

   //HERE ANIMATION AND CHOOSE WHAT SPRITE = WHERE PLAYER IS LOOKING AT

   public void render(Screen screen){

    if (dir == 0) {
        sprite = Sprite.player_n;
        if (walking) {
            if (anim % 20 > 10){
                sprite = sprite.player_n1;
            } else {
                sprite = sprite.player_n2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dir == 1) {
        sprite = Sprite.player_e;
        if (walking) {
            if (anim % 20 > 10){
                sprite = sprite.player_e1;
            } else {
                sprite = sprite.player_e2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dir == 2) {
        sprite = Sprite.player_s;
        if (walking) {
            if (anim % 20 > 10){
                sprite = sprite.player_s1;
            } else {
                sprite = sprite.player_s2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dir == 3) {
        sprite = Sprite.player_w;
        if (walking) {
            if (anim % 20 > 10){
                sprite = sprite.player_w1;
            } else {
                sprite = sprite.player_w2;
            }
        }
    }

    // ADDING OFFSET CUZ THE PLAYER IS DOUBLE THE SIZE OF THE TILE

    int xx = x - 42;
    int yy = y - 42;

    screen.renderMob(xx, yy, sprite);

}


    //THIS IS HOW I MOVE THE PLAYER

    public void move(int xa, int ya){

    if (xa != 0 && ya != 0){
        move(xa, 0);
        move(0, ya);
        return;
    }

    if (xa > 0) dir = 1;
    if (xa < 0) dir = 3;
    if (ya > 0) dir = 2;
    if (ya < 0) dir = 0;

    if(!collision(xa, 0)){
            x += xa;
    }
    if(!collision(0, ya)){
            y += ya;
    }

}
```

**Thanks alooot!**

**Run method!

```
    public void run() {
    long xlastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer     = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    final double xns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    int frames   = 0;
    requestFocus();
    while(running){
        long xnow = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (xnow-xlastTime) / xns;
        xlastTime = xnow;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            update();
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            frame.setTitle(title + " | " + frames + " fps");
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();

}
```

Comment: Much more details about how you are actually representing (and painting!) the player and the game loop are required here...

Comment: Mmmm, let me try to give more info.

Comment: The relevant information is still rather scattered in (or even not contained in) the provided code. Roughly: You have a tile position (which seems to be passed to the "renderMob" method). For the animation, you need an *additional* offset within the tile. This offset could, for example, be modified by a `javax.swing.Timer` that increments the offset every 20 milliseconds and triggers a repaint. (But ... your painting seems to consist of *setting pixels in an array* - which is rather unusual, so I'm not entirely sure whether this will work for your...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is declare two int fields in the player class:

```
private float xToMove = 0;
private float yToMove = 0;
```

Then, under your input event:

```
if (input.down && yToMove == 0)  
    yToMove = -32;
if (input.up && yToMove == 0)    
    yToMove = 32;
if (input.left && xToMove == 0) 
    xToMove = -32;
if (input.right && xToMove == 0) 
    xToMove = 32;
```

And finally, in your Player class's update method:

```
public void update()
{
    if (xToMove > 0)
    {
        xToMove--;
        x++;
    }
    if (xToMove < 0)
    {
        xToMove++;
        x--;
    }
    if (yToMove > 0)
    {
        yToMove--;
        y++;
    }
    if (yToMove < 0)
    {
        yToMove++;
        y--;
    }
}
```

Of course this is simplified a bit but the concept is there

EDIT: to change the speed. Note that xToMove and yToMove have been changed to floats.

You can use a float to represent the amount of time 1 move takes

```
float period = 1000; //The time one move takes in milliseconds
```

Somewhere you should calculate the number of pixels to be moved each frame. You could make a calculateSpeed() method or just throw it into the constructor or something. Depends on if you want speed to change during the game.

```
float speed = 32f / (fps * (period / 1000f));  //fps should be obtained dynamically and should be a float
```

Then when you update you should do this:

```
if (xToMove > 0)
{
    xToMove -= speed;
    x += speed;
    if (xToMove <= 0)
    {
        //Set these guys to nice even numbers to prevent problems
        xToMove = 0;
        x = (float) Math.round(x);
    }
}
```

Also make sure that x and y are floats.

EDIT 2: fps

```
int frames   = 0;
int fps = 60;
requestFocus();
while(running){
    long xnow = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (xnow-xlastTime) / xns;
    xlastTime = xnow;
    while (delta >= 1) {
        update();
        delta--;
    }
    render();
    frames++;

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
        timer += 1000;
        fps = frames;
        frame.setTitle(title + " | " + fps + " fps");
        frames = 0;
    }
}
stop();
```

Comment: I finally got it to kindda work, but now when i move randomly more than like 3 times around, i start getting weird x and y values like = X = 12.9375 instead of 13..., is there a way i can always make it to 1, 2 ,3 type like (int) when hes not moving? or like a snap to tile method maybe?

Comment: At the end of every movement just use "x = (float) Math.round(x);" to round your coordinates off to the nearest integer.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought that line will do when u used it, but am still geting non rounded numbers.. mm.. maybe cuz those X and Y are then divided by 32?

Comment: Are you sure that part of the code is being reached? It's possible you're using the wrong comparison (>= when you should be using <= or vice versa) and the rounding function is never called.

Comment: Yea, the rounding is reached the thing is i m dividing that output somewhere in my code , when i output that X directly and round it, its ok, but when i display it on my game and to the render it gets divided by 32 and then the error comes..., yeah your code is working, is something am doing wrong implementing it on my rendering

Comment: You could call the rounding method AFTER you divide it by 32

Comment: OH, maybe cuz am doing this at my render; screen.renderMob((int)x, (int)y, sprite);

Comment: If you're casting to an int there should be no decimal point at all. Although I would recommend this as it just truncates the fractional part. For example, (int)15.99999 becomes 15

Comment: The problem is that floats are calculated to a limited number of decimal points, so any time you do math with floats there will be a very small offset that adds up every time you do another operation

Comment: I thin it may be something to do on how i get those frames on each update, i think i should be using a delta thingie or something like every1 does.....     :(

Comment: When you calculate the speed it's important that your value for fps is accurate

Comment: Mmm, maybe should i try to use BigDecimal?

Comment: No I wouldn't do that. Just round them off before you use them for whatever it is that's giving you problems.

Comment: Still can't figure it out... ;(

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Using the code u mentioned, am going allways a little bit farther than 32, so my x or y end up being exact rounded like 448.0 BUT thats not where player should be, i found out that doing the math on the speed makes that problem to happend or not to happend depending on the 'period', so i can tell theres something wrong calculating the speed math with those floats... or maybe the x = (float)Math.round(x);

Comment: maybe am doing something wrong getting the frames? am just feeding the frames from my main to my player update, the same that i display at my window tile...

Comment: Make a separate variable called fps. You can still use 'frames', but only update 'fps' at the end of every second. Then use 'fps' in your speed calculations. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Did that, getting same results, it is obviusly something wrong happening when doing maths with those floats , dividing and then adding them to the current x or y..